# python twitter module does not see _file_cache load during __init__ when using IPython

Tags: python, twitter

While trying to `'import twitter'` when using `PyCharm` or `IPython` with the `Anaconda3` code set (after twitter installed using pip), the twitter module does not 'see' the `_file_cache` module and generates an error during `__init__`.
 The `_file_cache` module is in fact present (and was reloaded to confirm it was not corrupt).  A similar import of twitter using IDLE on a standard `Py34` load works fine.

Any idea why the problem with Anaconda3/PyCharm/IPython?

```
ImportError  
---> 31 from _file_cache import _FileCache

ImportError: No module named '_file_cache'
```

Answer (score -1):

This is likely because python-twitter [does not support python 3 yet,](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/issues/209) and thus is not explicit about relative imports (which python 3 requires).